# how to update database after using a jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a Sortable as explained in this [code](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) to drag Items around in a calender week view.
When i refresh the page, the items are always at the original place as i don't update the database after a drag action.

I already got this code to get the id of the dragged item (ui.item[0].dataset.accesskey) and the name of the list i drag it to, so i just have to call a php function to update my database with this data.

```
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable0, #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5, #sortable6" ).sortable({
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log(event.target.id);
      console.log(ui.item[0].dataset.accesskey);
      makeHandler_updateDraggedTask(ui.item[0].dataset.accesskey);
    }
  }).disableSelection();
} );
</script>
```

I just can't figure out how i call a php function with the information i got there. The makeHandler_updateDraggedTask is a very bad try to do that and it doesn't hold any code right now. How am i able to solve my Problem?

Best regards Alex

Comment: **Tip:** Try an attribute _"starts-with"_ selector `$('ul[id^="sortable"]')` or add a class to your unordered lists e.g. `<ul class="sortable-list">`.

Comment: Also, I would not alter the database on drag release... You should monitor the state of the rows and if they have changed, allow the user to "commit" the change back to the server/database.